# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {} failed. Access is denied

Tags: visual-studio-2013, excel-interop

I have developed an application with options to export and import excel data. This is working fine in local machines. But when i tried to deploy in server machine. it showing the following

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 

failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 
(E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

My server machine is windows server 2008 R2(64bit)

any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Just google the error message, thousands of hits.  You don't need another one.

Comment: @HansPassant i tried with almost everything..but still the message is returning the same

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found several articles, that you shouldn't use Office Interop on the server, because:

It uses the actual Office Application in the end
That makes it slow and resource consuming
It's hard to handle multiple requests at the same time
If the code fails, the application might keep running => it might never work again, until you restart the process

Instead of interop i used EPPlus.dll and the problem resolved!